# Como impedir arquivo principal index.php de ser apagado?

Tags: php

admin.php:

```
$file = $_GET['apagar'];
if (!unlink($file))
{
echo ("arquivo nao encontrado");
}
else
{
echo ("arquivo deletado");
}

 <script>function del(){return confirm("Excluir?");}</script>
 <a href='?apagar=data1.html' onclick='return del();'>Apagar</a>
 <a href='?apagar=data2.html' onclick='return del();'>Apagar</a>
 <a href='?apagar=data3.html' onclick='return del();'>Apagar</a>
```

Até aqui tudo bem!

O problema está aqui, acessando a url direta apaga o arquivo index.php coisa que não quero.

```
http://127.0.0.1/admin.php?apagar=index.php
```

Comment: A melhor forma é ter uma lista de arquivos na BD e só deixar apagar se ele existir. Ou então ter os arquivos que são para apagar num diretório diferente dos arquivos `.php`.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mesmo deixando em uma pasta diferente é possível apagar acesso direto http://127.0.0.1/admin.php?apagar=../config.php deleta arquivos mais importante ainda. :-|

Comment: tens de tirar o acesso a essas pastas primeiro e dar acesso só à pasta onde vão estar os ficheiros.

Comment: você pode fazer uma lista no banco de dados como o Jorge B. sugeriu ou um array com as paginas que não quer que sejam apagadas e antes da execução do `unlink($file)` vc verificar se o que veio no `$_GET["apagar"]` esta presente na lista com um `in_array()`, se estiver vc interrompe a execução

Comment: Alias o ideal é teres um diretório só para ficheiros que podem ser editados e apagados e também um registo desses mesmos ficheiro em BD, e só apagar se estiverem na BD e claro naquele diretório. Os restantes diretórios devem estar protegidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua preocupação neste momento é que um usuário mal intencionado consiga excluir arquivos *.php do seu site, mas isso deixa aberto para um atacante tentar excluir QUALQUER ARQUIVO do seu host, se as permissões de pastas estiverem mal configuradas seu servidor estará exposto e você poderá ter muita dor de cabeça.

Uma solução melhor é manter um diretório a parte especificamente para este tipo de arquivo e o seu script tem que checar se o arquivo solicitado para exclusão se encontra neste diretório, por exemplo:

```php
<?php

$userFiles = '/caminho/pasta/especifica';
$fileRequested = basename($_GET['apagar']);
$file = $userFiles . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileRequested;
if (is_file($file) && unlink($file)) {
    echo 'arquivo deletado';
} else {
    echo 'arquivo não encontrado ou não autorizado';
}

// ...
```